# Python list() is not creating list of dictionary correctly

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following variables:

```
klasa = '3b'
szkola = 'gimnazjum'
```

When I'm creating a dictionary and trying to do a list from this, dictionary is corruped:

```
In [12]: list(({'szkola':szkola, 'klasa':klasa}))
Out[12]: ['szkola', 'klasa']
```

But when I'm doing this more simple, then everything is ok:

```
In [11]: [{'szkola':szkola, 'klasa':klasa}]
Out[11]: [{'klasa': '3b', 'szkola': 'gimnazjum'}]
```

Is there any possible to create list of dictionary by using `list()` function?

Comment: `{}.items()` is way to do.

Comment: @vishes_shell it's creating list of touples, but I want to create list of dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an empy list and append dictionaries:

```
klasa = '3b'
szkola = 'gimnazjum'

d = {'szkola':szkola, 'klasa':klasa}
l = []

l.append(d)
```

> [{'klasa': '3b', 'szkola': 'gimnazjum'}]